# How to use an input from a select option in html with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to assign a drop down option to a unique ID so that when it is selected, the javascript will take that ID and turn it into a variable which I can use to display the cost.

This is what I have so far:

```
<form>
        <select>
        <option name ="Bristol "value="40.0" id="BN1">Bristol - Newcastle</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" onclick="BookingFare(); return false;">Submit</button><br>
        </form>

function BookingFare() { 


            var price = 0;
            //var ofAdults = document.getElementById('adults').value;
            //var ofChildren = document.getElementById('children').value;
            var BN1 = document.getElementById('BN1').value;

            if (BN1) {
             var price = price + 40; 
            }

            document.getElementById('priceBox').innerHTML = price;

            }
```

I can't get it to display the price, even when I just try to get it to print out "hello" when BN1 is selected it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure you have an element with the id of `priceBox`?

Comment: yes sorry just didnt show it in html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function BookingFare() { 


            var price = 0;
            //var ofAdults = getElementById('adults').value;
            //var ofChildren = getElementById('children').value;
            var BN1 = document.getElementById('BN1').value;

            if (BN1) {
             var price = price + 40; 
            }

            document.getElementById('priceBox').innerHTML = price;

            }
```

```html
<form>
        <select id="BN1">
        <option name ="Bristol "value="40.0" >Bristol - Newcastle</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" onclick="BookingFare(); return false;">Submit</button><br>
        </form>

<label id='priceBox'></label>
```

Comment: Assuming you have more than just one route in the select, you probably want price = BN1; in the if block, otherwise why bother specifying the price in the option elements.

Comment: Yeah just copied what the OP stated.. It's his discretion now

Comment: Okay yep i have noticed when i add more options in this way is no good i am sorry about that, i have done your way now price = BN1 in if statements but all it does is take the if statement at the bottom and use that price for whatever i use. Any suggestions?